# javascript reusable function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

people, I have a question. I have two javascript functions that do the same thing. Note that it only changes the "let selected" variable. I don't think it's the best way to use functions in js, how can I reuse them?

First function:

```
onChange(id) {
    let selected = this.state.selectedDevice
    let find = selected.indexOf(id)

            if(find > -1) {
                selected.splice(find, 1)
            } else {
                selected.push(id)
            }

            this.setState({ selected })
        }
```

Second function:

```
onChangeSec(id) {
            let selected = this.state.selectedSection
            let find = selected.indexOf(id)

            if(find > -1) {
                selected.splice(find, 1)
            } else {
                selected.push(id)
            }

            this.setState({ selected })
        }
```

thanks !!!

Comment: Make `selected` another parameter you can pass in…?

Comment: You could also pass in the `name` of the relevant property as a string and access `this.state[name]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass key as another function parameter

```
onChange(id, key) {
        let selected = this.state[key]
        let find = selected.indexOf(id)

        if(find > -1) {
            selected.splice(find, 1)
        } else {
            selected.push(id)
        }

        this.setState({ selected })
}
```

and in your case key would be 'selectedDevice' or 'selectedSection' passed as a string.

Comment: and how would i pass this string? in my case I have these 2 arrays. Thanks for the answer

Comment: What about onChange(5, 'selectedDevice') for example?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `this.state.selectedDevice` and `this.state.selectedSection` are both arrays, and since you're using index-based retrieval from the array, there's no way from within the function to determine which should be used. Instead you should pass that information into the function. For example:

```js
onChange(id, data) {
  const position = data.indexOf(id)
  
  this.setState({
    selected: position > -1
      ? [...data.slice(0, position), ...data.slice(position + 1)]
      : [...data, 1]
  })
}
```

Note: this also works around your mutation of an object in state, which will cause bugs.

You might also want to consider using a `Set` instead:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    selected: new Set()
  }
}

onChange(value) {
  const newSelected = new Set(this.state.selected)

  if (newSelected.has(value)) {
    newSelected.delete(value)
  } else {
    newSelected.add(value)
  }

  this.setState({ selected: newSelected })
}
```

This is safer than an array where you can have multiple entries of the same value.